# How to make ImageView click change another ImageViews background image

Tags: java, android, xml, onclick, imageview

How do you make the press of an imageview change another imageviews background image?

My code keeps giving me a null pointer exception error but I dont know why.

The java  code

```
ImageView imageview2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
public void onclickname(View v) {
    imageview2.setImageResource(R.drawable.example);}
```

The clickable imageview

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/example"
        android:id="@+id/imageview1"
        android:onClick="onclickname"/>
```

The imageview whos background image i want to change.

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/red"
        android:id="@+id/imageview2"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> imageview1 and imageview2 are in separate activities.

that's why you are getting null pointer exception.The image view is not found by your activity's layout(It is not appearing on screen).
and your `imageview2` is always null.

Comment: This isn't the problem as I tried this code with an imageview in the same activity and still got the same error. Do you know a better way to change the background image of a seperate activity?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the background of a `View` that is not in your current `Activity` (not visible) then you could store a flag (boolean) or some int counter which you could pass to the next activity using [`putExtra`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7325248/4083565).

Then in the onCreate of the second `Activity` you could use an `if` statement to check what to set the background to using `getExtra` after initializing the imageview2.

I think that was the `nullPointerException` that you were getting.